# Performance difference between summing iterator of 1 with if v.s. iterator of boolean condition

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension

Would there be a performance difference between

`sum(1 for x in a_list if x.some_condition())`

and

`sum(x.some_condition() for x in a_list))` ?

Assuming that x.some_condition returns a boolean.

I am asking because I was told that list comprehension were highly optimized, so I was curious on what was the more optimized between those two, since in the first case we are always summing the same integer and might take advantage of branch prediction, while on the other case, we can only predict the number of items in that iterator

Comment: I really suspect that you won't be able to tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

"highly optimized" is relative... **Both are very slow** because of the CPython interpreter (especially due to the *reference counting* of each object in the list). As for PyPy which is a JIT, it does not optimize list comprehensions very well (and prefer trivial range-based loops). Still list comprehension are faster than classical loops.

The former should be slightly faster if most objects `x.some_condition()` is mostly always false. Indeed, in that case, the length of the generated iterable will be very small and the cost of `sum` very small. Otherwise, the latter should be slightly faster since conditions generally slower than branch-less operations (especially if the condition cannot be easily predicted by the processor).

Note that `sum(map(Class.some_condition, a_list))` should be a bit faster since `map` is written in C.